# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'axes'

Tags: python, django

I installed django-axes using pip command

```
$ pip install django-axes
```

Then I've added axes to my Installed Apps as shown below

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'axes',
    'frontend',
    'userauth',
    'methods',

]
```

But when I run command

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

I get error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'axes'

Comment: post the complete traceback

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? Did you definitely install `django-axes` in the correct place?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe activate your virtualenv. Make sure you've installed it in your virtualenv itself.

Answer (score 2):

check yourself you're in virutalenv ( if you installed in it),

use `pip list` or `pip freeze`

```
(myapp) mohideen@botvfx-dev:~/project/myapp/myApp$ pip list | grep axes
django-axes (2.3.3)
```

if its there.. then you can use it..

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sureyou Django version is supported by your version of django-axes

2) Remember to run python manage.py migrate to sync the database.
refer - https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html